# Importing a library to into Intellij Idea platform sdk

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, import, javaparser, platform-sdk

I am developing a plugin using Intellij Idea using platform SDK! I want to import the JavaParser library available at

```
https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser
```

so that I can parse java source code. The importing can be done using gradle and maven but I dont know how to use it for the Intellij Idea platform SDK. How can I import the library into my project?

Comment: Did you take a look at the quickstart projects mentioned at [link](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) ?